# Setting a cookie by PHP to be used by ASPX

Tags: php, asp.net, cookies

I had no choice but to use .NET for building a search page since my buisness partner who needs a new website uses MSSQL for his database.

However in my current situation I have no choice but to do so so I'm building an HTML5/.NET hybrid.

I have a webpage built in ASPX that when loaded by default, it searches the inventory database based on a cookie parameter that's set like this:

> COOKIE NAME: "searchParameter" COOKIE VALUE: "valueC=stringSearch"

But I cannot replicate the cookie above in PHP because the equals sign '=' is removed in PHP

> COOKIE NAME: "searchParameter" COOKIE VALUE: "valueC%3DstringSearch"

So in PHP the equals sign goes from '=' to '%3D' and therefore, the ASPX page will not perform the proper search based on the cookie that's set in the previous PHP page.

How can I set a cookie value with a '=' character in it so it doesn't change to %3D?

This is what I have so far in PHP:

```
<?php
$value = 'valueC=stringSearch';

setcookie("searchParameter", $value);
setcookie("searchParameter", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
setcookie("searchParameter", $value, time()+3600, "/", "cinicraft.com", 1);
?>
```

But when checking the currently stored cookies with Google Chrome developer tools, I get this:

> COOKIE NAME: "searchParameter" COOKIE VALUE: "valueC%3DstringSearch"

This will not work with the aspx page unless I can get the cookie value to be "valueC=stringSearch"

Does anyone here know how to get the '=' in PHP with cookies?

Comment: @SamuelCook If you can add FreeTDS to your server that is (if using Linux).  If you're on a Windows machine it may be easier.

Comment: PDO also has a mssql driver

Comment: @user2636774 have you tried setting the cookies using `header()` instead of the `setcookie()` shortcut?

Comment: the `%3D` is a url encoded `=`. I would assume .NET has a urldecode function somewhere.

Comment: I've tried PHP with MSSQL, it's a nightmare and it was impossible to set up. It's faster for me just to build a hybrid instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

- urldecoding the value on ASP
- using `header()` to set the cookie header
- using [`setrawcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setrawcookie.php) to avoid the auto-urlencoding as the docs on [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) says